# Memoir class \paragraphfootstyle: Can paragraphed footnotes be split?

Tags: footnotes, memoir, paragraphs, reledmac, bigfoot

I am trying to get footnotes typeset in paragraphs, but with more than one paragraph of footnotes per page.

This is to achieve a layout common in critical editions of Latin liturgical texts, such as Deshusses's edition of the Sacramentaire grégorien (photo attached). You can see in the image how there is a separate paragraph of notes (giving textual variants) for each numbered paragraph of text in the edition on the upper part of the page. [image: Deshusses Sacramentaire gregorien]

I've been trying to achieve this using the footnote customization capabilities of the memoir class, as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{numberedtextpara}
\newcommand{\printnumberedtextpara}{{\textbf{\arabic{numberedtextpara}.}\ }}

\newfootnoteseries{Variant}
\paragraphfootstyle{Variant}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteVariant}{\alph{footnoteVariant}}
\footmarkstyleVariant{\ifthenelse{\value{footnoteVariant}>1}{\textsuperscript{#1}}{\textbf{\arabic{numberedtextpara}.}\ \textsuperscript{#1}}}

\newfootnoteseries{Sources}
\plainfootstyle{Sources}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteSources}{}
\footmarkstyleSources{\textbf{\arabic{numberedtextpara}.\ }}


\begin{document}

\refstepcounter{numberedtextpara}
\setcounter{footnoteVariant}{0}
\printnumberedtextpara Here\footnoteSources{Where this text comes from.} is\footnoteVariant{are \emph{A}} some text that will have a paragraph number. It will need\footnoteVariant{require \emph{B}} one layer of footnotes that refers to sources, and another that refers to textual variants.\footnoteVariant{Yo!\break}

\refstepcounter{numberedtextpara}
\setcounter{footnoteVariant}{0}
\printnumberedtextpara Here\footnoteSources{But this comes from somewhere else.} is yet\footnoteVariant{still \emph{A}} another numbered paragraph, which will have some footnotes\footnoteVariant{at least some footnotes \emph{B}}.
\end{document}
```

As you can see, I've been able to get the paragraph number to print before the first footnote of each numbered paragraph. But is there anything I can do to insert a line/paragraph break before the paragraph number in the first layer of footnotes? Nothing I've tried seems to work.

I've been looking through the documentation of the bigfoot package, which seems like it might be adaptable to this need. But the code is, I'm afraid, beyond my competence. I've also done a good deal of experimenting with the reledmac package, but without success in this particular need.

Comment: You could simply create three apparatuses using Reledmac – you can change the spacing between each one manually if needed. But I feel as if I am missing something.

Comment: Sorry, hadn't read carefully enough. I think it should be possible to use the paragraph numbering as a label, and perhaps use something along the lines of `\AtStartEveryPstart` to create a new paragraph in the apparatus – although I suppose what you really want is the equivalent of a heading for each numbered heading. I would perhaps question the wisdom of Deshusses' typesetters instead …

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. (Enjoying the UK?) What might go in that \AtStartEveryPstart? I've managed to persuade reledmac to insert a paragraph number in front *every* critical note keyed to a line number, which accomplishes much the same thing. But it's actually a bit harder on the reader. (Maieul indicated a while ago that he couldn't see any easy way to do separate paragraphs of notes in reledmac.) Really I'm going more for the layout in Andrieu's edition of the Ordines Romani (which uses footnote markers instead of line numbers).

Comment: maybe, a possible feature, will be to add in reledmac an option similar to `Xgroupbyline`, but for paragraph. It should implie some dev from myself. So please open an issue with a MWE.